# What is the significant difference between typescript versus Babel?

Tags: babeljs, typescript2.0

To make the app ES6 ready, I read two tools. Both are great according to some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great answer for this question has been provided by **John Papa** at [Understanding ES5, ES2015 and TypeScript](https://johnpapa.net/es5-es2015-typescript/)

Here I quote:

From the top of the TypeScript website’s front page we find this statement:

`TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript.`

> This is hugely important. TypeScript is not a
>   shortcut language. It doesn’t deviate from JavaScript. It doesn’t take
>   us in another direction. It’s purpose is to allow us to use features
>   in the future versions of JavaScript today, and to provide a better
>   and safer experience.

Typescript introduces interfaces and types.

```
interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

function greeter(person: Person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}
```

Comment: So it is safe to assume that Typescript is just a Transpiler and browser's does not full support of Typescript instead ES6 feature. Since ES6 and typescript are not entirely the same.

Comment: yes, `typescript` compiles to `javascript` you are not going to include `.ts` files in ur `html` template. U will include compiled `.js` files